# Transform XML with XSL produces plain text output

Tags: xml, xslt, maximo

This is my first time round using .xsl so should be an easy question.

I have this xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PublishTESTWS1ASSET xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creationDateTime="2017-01-22T20:07:28-08:00" transLanguage="EN" baseLanguage="EN" messageID="3649776.1485144448726917270" maximoVersion="7 6 20141117-2230 V7600-218" event="0">
   <TESTWS1ASSETSet>
      <ASSET>
         <ASSETID>52</ASSETID>
         <ASSETNUM>1001</ASSETNUM>
         <DESCRIPTION>Fire Extinguisher</DESCRIPTION>
      </ASSET>
   </TESTWS1ASSETSet>
</PublishTESTWS1ASSET>
```

And I have this .xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testws1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="PublishTESTWS1ASSET/TESTWS1ASSETSet">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ASSET"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ASSET">
         <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testws1/">
         <soapenv:Header/>
         <soapenv:Body>
            <tes:addAsset>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/></name>
               <number><xsl:value-of select="ASSETID"/></number>
            </tes:addAsset>
       </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this gets transformed it puts out the following in plain text

```
     52
     1001
     Fire Extinguisher
```

I've narrowed it down to the attribute in PublishTESTWS1ASSET

```
xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo"
```

Removing that produces the right output

```
  <soapenv:Envelope 
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:tes="http://testws1/"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:addAsset>
         <name>Fire Extinguisher</name>
         <number>52</number>
      </tes:addAsset>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can somebody explain to me why this is happening and how to fix it without changing the original xml document

Comment: Search for "XSLT default namespace" and you will find 574 answers to this same question.

Answer (score 1):

You are not matching the namespace in the XSLT; without this the templates you've written won't match the elements of input XML. And the reason you are getting some output is there are built-in templates that process your input XML.

You need to declare the namespace(and a prefix, optionally) in  your XSLT and use them to match elements.
Please refer the code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testws1/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns="http://www.ibm.com/maximo">
   <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="ns:PublishTESTWS1ASSET/ns:TESTWS1ASSETSet">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ns:ASSET"/>
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="ns:ASSET">
         <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://testws1/">
         <soapenv:Header/>
         <soapenv:Body>
            <tes:addAsset>
                <name><xsl:value-of select="ns:DESCRIPTION"/></name>
               <number><xsl:value-of select="ns:ASSETID"/></number>
            </tes:addAsset>
       </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the XSLT above, the namespace `http://www.ibm.com/maximo` is declared with the prefix `ns`. And in rest of the XPATHs, to match the elements, the same prefix is used.